# How to use a ternary operator within a map function?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a ternary operator within a map function. I'm not quite sure what I am doing, as I have this so far, basically I want to pass the item.test_type into the options props.

```
 {allTestTypes.map(item => item.test_type )}

      {!level ? null :
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
          <DropdownSingle 
            name={configs[level].name} 
            value={testType} 
            options={configs[level].dropdownValues} 
            onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "map over a ternary statement?". You map over arrays, not ternary statement. You could use a ternary operator within a map function (you aren't doing that here), Or you could use a ternary operator to optionally map over an array. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you can remove the ternary and just do something like `{level && <React.Fragment>...` since you have `null` there - makes the code read cleaner also

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. using a ternary operator within a map function. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not entirely clear what you’re asking. I don’t think “mapping over a ternary statement” means anything.

The best I can guess is that you’re trying to map over `allTestTypes` but only if `level !== null`.

First of all, in Javascript/React you can say:

```js
{ level && <SomeComponent/> }
```

which will only render the component if `level` is not null (i.e., truthy). If you wanted to be more specific than “truthy” and only check for null you could do

```js
{ level !== null && <SomeComponent/> }
```

I don’t have a “second of all” because I’m still not clear what you mean by "I want to pass the item.test_type into the options props.”

But, I wonder if maybe this is enough to solve whatever your problem is.

Comment: I've just updated the question :) sorry for the confusion! and yes that is what I meant.

Comment: I'm (completely) unclear of the purpose of the first line of your code, with the map statement itself, especially since that line is complete/closed within itself, and doesn't involve your ternary operator. If your question is fully answered you can mark this as the answer.

Comment: So, to clarify what you're asking for: When you responded to my comment above, you said you want to "use a ternary operator wtihin a map function". What you seem to be saying now is that you want to use a ternary operator to control whether or not you map over allTestTypes. Which is it? And is `allTestTypes` supposed to be used to populate your `options` parameter in `DropdownSingle`?

Comment: Yes, it i s to control whether or not you map over allTestTypes and yes allTestTypes is supposed to be used to populate my options parameter in dropDownSingle